# Create a mask for 14 digits number

Tags: reactjs, mask

How can I create a mask via [react-text-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-text-mask) that can have only 14 digits?

Something like this:

```
export default function NumberMask(props) {

const { inputRef, ...other } = props;

return (
    <MaskedInput
        {...other}
        ref={(ref) => {
            inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null);
        }}
        mask={[?? , '______________']}
        placeholderChar={'\u2000'}
        size={14}
        showMask
    />
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a regular expression

```
/\d{14}/g
```

regarding react-text-mask I guess

```
mask={[/\d{14}/]}
```