# TextField List based on a defined mask

Tags: reactjs, regex, material-ui

I have this component that enable to enter one number of a 14 digits.

```
       const [account, setAccount] = useState('');
       const handleAccountChange = (event) => { setAccount(event.target.value) }

        <TextField
            id="filter-by-account"
            label="Search by: account "
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            value={account}
            onChange={handleAccountChange}
            InputProps={{ inputComponent: AccountNumberMask }}
       />
```

[Mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-text-mask):

```
return (
    <MaskedInput
        {...other}
        ref={(ref) => {
            inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null);
        }}
        mask={[/[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]}
        showMask
        onChange={() => { }}
        onBlur={() => { }}
    />
);
```

I need to update this component to except a list of 14 digits numbers rather than only one.

TextField example:
[image]

Appreciate your advice.

Thank you

Comment: Feels like you asked the exact same thing yesterday
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64976153/create-a-mask-for-14-digits-number/64976406#64976406

Comment: https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries

Comment: Its not. I want the option to insert list of numbers something like that : 1111 1111 1111 11 , 2222 2222 2222 22 , etc ....

Comment: Check this out, feels like the main issue here are regular expressions :) https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

As regular expression

```regex
/^\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{2}$/g
```

```js
mask={[/^\d{4} \d{4} \d{4} \d{2}$/]}
```

*Update after comment from question author*

Working example with [example from material-ui](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries)

```js
import * as React from "react";
import MaskedInput from "react-text-mask";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  }
}));

const TextMaskCustom = React.forwardRef(function TextMaskCustom(props, ref) {
  const setRef = React.useCallback(
    (maskedInputRef) => {
      const value = maskedInputRef ? maskedInputRef.inputElement : null;

      if (typeof ref === "function") {
        ref(value);
      } else if (ref) {
        ref.current = value;
      }
    },
    [ref]
  );

  return (
    <MaskedInput
      {...props}
      ref={setRef}
      mask={[
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        " ",
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        " ",
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        " ",
        /\d/,
        /\d/
      ]}
      placeholderChar={"\u2000"}
      showMask
    />
  );
});

export default function FormattedInputs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    textmask: "1111 1111 1111 11",
    numberformat: "1320"
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="formatted-text-mask-input">
          react-text-mask
        </InputLabel>
        <Input
          value={values.textmask}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="textmask"
          id="formatted-text-mask-input"
          inputComponent={TextMaskCustom}
        />
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

looks like [react-text-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-text-mask) is checking each value separately

```js
mask={[
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        " ",
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        " ",
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        " ",
        /\d/,
        /\d/
      ]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Julian. Regarding the regexp you are correct but my main problem is that I am not sure how to incorporate this in the component.

Comment: @angus I added a working example, tested in sandbox, let me know if that helps

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. Basically what I am looking for is something like the multiple option in https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

Comment: Do you mean to use the `renderInput` from `Autocomplete`?

Comment: I added a picture so the first number is ‘1111 1111 1111 11’ the second is ‘2222 2222 2222 22’ the third is ‘7896 4565 1555 22’ and if the user want to add another 10 more numbers he can do that. Still all of them have to be in the same pattern. Apologized for not being clear.